# Change "My Account" to "Username" WooCommerce sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, userinfo

I want to display for users once logged in instead of the default word My Account I want to display the user's name, I tried this code but it doesnt display anything!

It seems it doesn't recognized the variable `$current_user`in the file located at: wp-content/themes/themeName/framework/functions/woo-account.php

```
printf( __( '%s', 'wpdance' ),$current_user->user_lastname);
```

it was:

```
printf( __( 'My Account', 'wpdance' ));
```

And I tried also to get every thing using this code:

```
<?php global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
  echo 'User level: ' . $current_user->user_level . "\n";
  echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
  echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
  echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
```

?>

But `User first name:` and `User last name:` were empty!

Does someone have any suggestion or idea?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Did you try `printf( __( $current_user->user_lastname, 'wpdance' ));` ?

Comment: I jst did that and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `wp_get_current_user()` *(no need of any global variable)* and a conditional to be sure that the user is logged in:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_last_name = $user_info->user_lastname;
    printf( __( '%s', 'wpdance' ), $user_last_name );
}
```

Or with complete name:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_complete_name = $user_info->user_firstname . ' ' . $user_info->user_lastname;
    printf( __( '%s', 'wpdance' ), $user_complete_name );
}
```

References:

- [Get currentuserinfo firstname and lastname](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173078/get-currentuserinfo-firstname-and-lastname/173081#173081)
- [Function Reference/wp get current user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer but it doesn't display anything!

Comment: The error is:
`Notice: La méthode du constructeur appelée pour WP_Widget dans mgwoocommercebrands_list_widget est obsolète depuis la version 4.3.0 ! Utilisez

__construct()

à la place. in /home/epicerymarket/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3718`
Do you have any idea?

Comment: I got you, you are right, your code is corret! so I have another issue I will post new question about it!

Comment: @AbdelazizMirad You are not using the right way to make your widget since wordpress 4.3. But this is an other question (Une autre question). Here you have a solution in french: [Notice: WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/notice-wp_widget-is-deprecated-since-version-430). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

before

```
printf( __( '%s', 'wpdance' ),$current_user->user_lastname);
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo#Examples

And are you sure the lastname is always set? Probably you can make sure `$current_user` works, if `$current_user->ID` at least returns a value.

And enable debugging in your `wp_config.php` might help as well to display all notices and errors:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it and had this error:
`Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in mgwoocommercebrands_list_widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /home/classi33/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3718` Do you have any idea?

Comment: And I think that has nithing to do with it!